# How to know if my Bluetooth HC-05 is connected through serial monitor

Tags: bluetooth

I want to connect a Bluetooth module to arduino and check if my module is connected or not.. Through serial monitor. Is there and particular code to connect with that?

Comment: i think thats not the answer what he want...
.
he (actually me :D) want to know is the bluetooth connect or disconnect when sistem is running, in my program if bluetooth connect i'll send using bluetooth, if not i'll send using sim800,,,,
.
if i pull the KEY pin to vcc, bluetooth be ATCommand Mode, i hope==

Answer (score 1):

If your board is actually a HC-05, you can

1. Pull the KEY pin to Vcc (see note)
2. Write the serial command `AT` on the serial interface
3. Look at the output: if you receive `AT` or `OK` then the module is connected, otherwise it is not

Note: The key pin is the number 34 on the SMT module (with the antenna pointing upwards, its the pin in the top-right corner). If you have a THT module (so the one with about 6 pins) MAYBE this pin is connected to one of the pins you don't usually use (they are named EN, STATE, ...). Check with a multimeter if it is connected to one of these. If it is not, then you'll have to solder a wire from it to an arduino pin.

If, on the other hand, your board is a HC-06 (almost identical to HC-05, but with a different firmware - it is a slave-only bt device), then keep it disconnected from the master and perform steps 2 and 3: when not connected, in fact, the HC-06 is already in AT mode.

More information on [this webpage](http://www.instructables.com/id/AT-command-mode-of-HC-05-Bluetooth-module/?ALLSTEPS)